# Imperavi Redactor integration to feincms/admin/

Tags: python, django, django-admin, redactor, feincms

From http://www.feincms.org/why/

> FeinCMS comes with a bundled rich text content consisting of a single
>   field. The default editor is a TinyMCE instance. Support for CKEditor
>   is included, and other rich text editors can be easily integrated.

I'm trying to integrate redactor(http://imperavi.com/redactor/)
to feincms/admin/ -- is there some manual or how-to?

I have tried `github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor` -- not working, only

> TypeError: $(...).redactor is not a function

in FireBug console.

You can find redactor files for tests on `github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor/tree/master/redactor/static/redactor`

Packages used: Django==1.6.1 + FeinCMS==1.9.1

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on github:

> Basically you have to write two functions: One which is called when
>   rich text editing functionality is added ("richify"), and another one
>   which is called when functionality is removed ("poorify"). The second
>   is necessary because rich text editors do not like being dragged
>   around; when dragging a rich text content type, it is first poorified
>   and then richified again as soon as the content type has been dropped
>   into its final position.

More information -- 
https://github.com/feincms/feincms/issues/512#issuecomment-33204227